# Documenting enums with structural commands (doxygen)

Tags: enums, documentation, doxygen

Generally, when you're documenting code using Doxygen, you place the comments directly before or after whatever it is you're documenting. However, I am now working with some code that uses structural commands to comment the code (as described here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands). Basically, all the documentation is just included at the beginning of a file.

Not a fan of this approach, but it seems to work for the most part, with the exception being enums. Here's an example of how the enum is documented.

```
/*! 
    \enum MyEnum 

    A description of the enum. 

    \var EnumValue1       

           \image html enumimage.png 

           Description of value. 

    \var EnumValue2     

           \image html enumimage.png 

            Description of value. 
*/
```

Doxygen is able to recognize the enum and all of its values, but it ignores the descriptions of the values. Could someone please tell me what the correct way is of documenting enums using structural commands? (I'd like to be able to avoid changing all of these to a format where you place the documentation before or after the value).

Comment: This appears to work fine in Doxygen 1.8.3.1. What version of Doxygen are you using? Are you using a default Doxygen configuration file? Could you provide a screen capture of the output you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\var MyEnum EnumValue1

Description of value.
```